# Not able to login using instabot

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I feel as if there as a bug I would have found it by now lol. Can anyone explain?

```
from instabot import Bot
my_bot = Bot()
my_bot.login(username = 'Example-username', password = 'Example- passord')
my_bot.follow('instagram')
```

the error messages:
2024-03-18 20:35:14,721 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
2024-03-18 20:35:14,723 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2024-03-18 20:35:16,822 - ERROR - Request returns 400 error!
2024-03-18 20:35:16,822 - INFO - Instagram's error message: You'll need to update Instagram to
the latest version before you
can use the app.
2024-03-18 20:35:16,823 - INFO - Error type: block_eu_user_login_in_old_app
2024-03-18 20:35:16,823 - ERROR - Failed to login go to instagram and change your password
2024-03-18 20:35:16,824 - INFO - Username or password is incorrect.

I promise the username and password were correct